# Lyapunov Indirect Method

Tags: stability-in-odes, nonlinear-dynamics

I have searched a reference (book/paper) where I could find a theorem related to the Lyapunov Indirect Method for ***any*** equilibrium point, but I have not found yet. I only found for the ***zero*** equilibrium point. Somebody can help me?

I am searching the following Theorem:

Let us consider the non-linear system $\dot{x}=f(x)$ with an ***arbitrary*** equilibrium point $\bar{x}$. This equilibrium point $\bar{x}$ is:

1. asymptotically stable if all eigenvalues of $Df(\bar{x})$ have negative real part;
2. unstable if at least one eigenvalue of $Df(\bar{x})$ has positive real part;

where $Df(\bar{x})$ is the Jacobin matrix of $f$ applied in the equilibrium point $\bar{x}$.

Thank you very much!

Ana

Comment: You can always make a coordinate transformation $y = x - \overline{x}$ and get a system with an equilibrium at the origin. This transformation preserves stability properties (as any orientation-preserving diffeomorphism, really), thus any conclusions that you draw for an equilibrium at the origin are valid for an equilibrium point of original system.